# Mongodb - Mapping relations - type Objectid

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model that will be a child object to my `User` model. It will be a one-to-many relationship (users will have many blocks). For me, in this situation, embedding is not the answer. So I tried adding a `user_id` to my `Block` model and an array of `block_ids` to my `User` model. My block looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Block',{
  name:String,
  status:String,
  type:String,
  user_id:String,
});
```

When I save a new block with the current user's id, it doesn't save that attribute. I think it's because I've declared in the schema for it to be of type String and not an Objectid, but I'm not sure how to declare it as an object id of the users model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Schema.Types.ObjectId instead of String

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;
module.exports = mongoose.model('Block',{
  name:String,
  status:String,
  type:String,
  user_id:Schema.Types.ObjectId
});
```

Comment: Where do you get `Schema` from? I get an error that Schema is undefined.

Comment: oh I forget var Schema=mongoose.Schema; now it's correct